# Is it possible to get a calendar by its email from google calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I would like to use the google calendar API in order to get a public calendar, is it possible to get it by its email ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CalendarList.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list#try-it) and [CalenarList.get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/get).